# QGraphicsScene::clear() and destructor performance

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am using a QGraphicsScene to display a very large number of items, often more than 100,000.  When I call delete the scene, it takes an unusually long time to complete, 10 seconds or more.

A bit of experimenting revealed that the QGraphicsScene::clear function is the slow part.  If I clear first and then delete, the clear is slow but the delete is fast.

Why is the QGraphicsScene destructor/clear function so slow, and is there any way I can speed it up?

Answer (score 5):

I discovered that the problem relates to the fact that my QGraphicsScene was being displayed in a QGraphicsView.  If I first called `view->setScene(0)` to remove my scene from the view, then the scene would delete much more quickly.

I figured it out by using callgrind to see which functions were being called during QGraphicsScene::clear, and I saw that QGraphicsView functions were taking up the time.  I'm not sure, but I suspect QGraphicsView is updating something about itself for *each* deleted object.

Comment: Most likely your scene uses the spatial index, and the index is being continuously updated. You could also temporarily disable the index with the same effect, I think.